# Yii - join tables into 1 huge table and access all columns directly

Tags: join, yii

I have a problem with joining tables into one huge table so that all colums are accessible without nested FORs or using relations in them. Situation is like this:

```
cars
========
id_producer (PK)
id_model (PK)
length
weight
...

texts
============
id_model (PK)
language (PK)
text
...
```

Tables share 1 key: id_model

I want to join these tables like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM cars c
JOIN texts t ON c.id_model = t.id_model
WHERE t.language = 'english'
```

.. it will return 1 row for each car.

SQL is easy, Yii is not :(

I tried to do it usinq scope or relation, but never got desired output. 
I want to write following:

```
$carsWithTexts = Cars::model()-> ... something ... ->findAll()

foreach ($carsWithTexts as $c)
{
    echo $c->id_producer;
    echo $c->id_model;
    echo $c->id_text;
}
```

.. No nested FORs, no relations or scopes in the FOR.

Is this possible? Or do i have to always use following construction:

```
$carsWithTexts = Cars::model()-> ... relation ... ->findAll()


foreach ($carsWithTexts as $c)
{
    echo $c->id_producer;
    echo $c->id_model;
    echo $c->relation[0]["id_text"]; // or nested for
}
```

I know I can use commands "with" and "together", I did, but it didnt work as I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yii is not difficult, you just need to read the documentation and apply their examples, what you wanna do can be done like this:

I'll asume you have generated the code using Gii, so the relation name (you can check it at Car class) will be **texts**. Now you have two approachs to do it, the easy way:

```
Cars::model()->with('texts')->findAll("texts.language = 'english'");
```

This will return all cars with its text information, where the text has english language. I recommend you to read [Relational Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-options) from the official guide to learn more about this.

And the other approach is to use CDbCommand to execute an SQL command like this:

```
$connection=Yii::app()->db;   // assuming you have configured a "db" connection
$command=$connection->createCommand();
$command->from('cars');
$command->join('texts', 't.id_model = texts.id_model');
$command->where('texts.language=:language', array(':id'=>'english'));
$rows=$command->queryAll();
```

This way is more SQL friendly but as you can see there are a lot of more PHP lines.

Comment: Hi.That's exactly how I did it, but still there is the nested array in returned result. To get texts I need to loap through the result (it's OK) but in each record there is another array with texts. So I have to write this: "$car->texts[0]->text" to get the text.
Is it because of the relation type "HAS_MANY"?

Comment: PS: I would love to write only "$car->text" = the "text" column would be added (and accessible) as a column to the cars table using JOIN.

Comment: PS2: Even if I use CdbCriteria and specify sections JOIN and CONDITION, I never get the desired form of result = everything on 1 row. (Even if relation is not used!)

Comment: Finaly I did it using a pure SQL query as you mentioned:
"$connection = Yii::app()->db;
$command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
$results = $command->queryAll();"

Comment: I'm glad it worked :) try to learn Yii relationships.It will help your life a lot.